# installing PyAudio on Raspbian OS Jessie

Tags: raspbian, audio, raspbian-jessie

I am trying to install PyAudio on Raspbian Jessie , but I am getting this error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/git/toxcore/build $ sudo pip install PyAudio
Downloading/unpacking PyAudio
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.9.tar.gz (289kB): 289kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-9SCVCA/PyAudio/setup.py) egg_info for package PyAudio

    warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'test'
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio
    building '_portaudio' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-9SCVCA/PyAudio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0Evtna-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7

copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7

running build_ext

building '_portaudio' extension

creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/src

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o

src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running this first sudo apt-get install python-dev

Comment: I got it by installing using `sudo pip3 install pyaudio`

Comment: You should make it clear in your question what version of Python you are using, And you should answer your own question.

Comment: I was installing toxygen which I later realised is python 3 based so then I reinstalled using pip3

Comment: @SteveRobillard I answered because I read the last comment. I think I will delete this answer since your first answer talks about the python-dev. But I think if we are using python 3 then it should be python3-dev. I have read it in some ubuntu forums during cryptography setup using pycrypto some days back.

Comment: @VaradAG I agree that is the most common cause, but if you read all of the comments his problem was he needed to use Python3 and hence pip3. Using pip3 he was able to install without further problem.

Comment: @SteveRobillard oho ok.. Got it. I'm sorry its my bad.

Comment: @VaradAG no problem happens to all of us. I wasn't trying to shoot you down or dampen your enthusiasm - just trying to make the answer fit the question, or more precisely the problem.